# How do I save an image returned by a webservice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, image-uploading

I have a webservice call that will return an image, now I want to save this image to the filesystem in the server.

The problem is, I cannot make the webservice call from the server, as the webservice application runs on each user machine and a request is made to the service as `http://localhost/get_image`, which returns the image.

How do I save this image on the server?

Comment: base64-encode it, POST to the server and save there.

Comment: What I am trying now is
$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:8080/image',      success: function(msg) {$('#some_field').val(Base64.encode(msg));$('#nuser').submit();      }      });

but the system hangs on the line Base64.encode

Comment: Base64 is probably not defined (it is not a core JS object).. Try downloading a JavaScript base64 encoding library ( http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=210)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML5 to load image using javascript and send base64 encoded response to sever where you can decode the response and write image to a file. Here is the approach

1. Create a form with following html elements

   - canvas element: to get the image
   - text area: to store the base 64 encoded response and send response to server
2. Ensure that the webservice response headers has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to allow cross origin resource sharing
3. Jquery code

> ```
> var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');    
> var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');    
> var img = new Image;    
> img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';    
> img.src = "web service url which returns image";    
> img.onload = function(){
>   console.log( img.width, img.height );
>   // set canvas height and width to image height and width else only part of image will get created
>   myCanvas.height = img.height;    
>   myCanvas.width = img.width;    
>   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like    
>   var dataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
>   dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");    
>   $('#some_text_area_id').val(dataURL); // set the response in text area    
>   $('#form_id').submit();   // submit the form
> };
> ```

1. Server side - Decode the response using "base64" ruby library

> ```
> File.open('test.png',"wb") do |file|
>   file.write(Base64.decode64(params[:text_area]))
> end
> ```

Comment: Make sure your browsers support HTML5. You can take test at http://html5test.com/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using carrierwave gem for url image upload

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?autoplay=true

Comment: The carries wave has an option for uploading the file using the image url, but the problem in my case is the image url will something like http://localhost:8080/image, as the images are fetched from a webservice requst from a client machine 
so the server wont get any image

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above base64 encoding should be used when transferring image over wire. Base64 represents binary data in an ASCII string format. Its specifically for MIME content transfer encoding and storing complex data in XML.

You can try Javascript base64 encoding decoding here http://rumkin.com/tools/compression/base64.php

Also, make sure you use file.write and file.read instead of file.puts and file.gets when you try to write png image files

```
File.open('a.png', 'rb') do |infile|
   File.open('b.png', 'wb') do |outfile|
      outfile.write(infile.read)
   end  
end
```

Though the best solution is to return image URL as web service response and fetch the image from the asset server.